# How to make a REST callout from CRM Analytics app?

Tags: integration, einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, crm-analytics

I am exploring CRM analytics and we created and connected to 3rd party database where we created Data sets and Data recipe and display dashboard accordingly.

My requirement is I have 2 columns Column A & Column B which contains some information and I want to pass this column under request body and I will get **URL information** in the response and that URL information I will have to store it somehow in my CRM analytics Dashboard column. Now these URL is not store as column in 3rd party database, 3rd party developers written some custom logic where if they get information from Column A & Column B then they will return URL in the response. Whatever data we fetch from 3rd party database, we are not storing it anywhere in Salesforce. Those data is just Read only for us.

Can someone please help what can be different possible that helps me to achieve this use case?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_overview.htm